# How do I un-transpose columns in mysql? Or how I convert multiple columns into one column? please see below

Tags: mysql

current table format:

| id | car | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | 123 |
| 1 | text | 456 |
| 3 | text | 897 |
| 3 | text | 908 |
| 3 | text | 900 |

desired format:

| column_name |
| --- |
| 1 |
| text |
| 123 |
| 1 |
| text |
| 456 |
| 3 |
| text |
| 897 |
| 3 |
| text |
| 908 |
| 3 |
| text |
| 900 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to get your required result, if the order is important for you, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT  T.unpivot_value                 AS  column_name
FROM
(
    SELECT  id                          AS  row_order,
            1                           AS  column_order,
            CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100))    AS  unpivot_value
    FROM    YourTable

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT  id                          AS  row_order,
            2                           AS  column_order,
            CAST(car AS VARCHAR(100))   AS  unpivot_value
    FROM    YourTable

    UNION   ALL

    SELECT  id                          AS  row_order,
            3                           AS  column_order,
            CAST(price AS VARCHAR(100)) AS  unpivot_value
    FROM    YourTable
)   AS      T

ORDER BY    T.row_order,
            T.column_order
```